# Computing importance measure using VIP package on a parsnip model

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidymodels

I am trying to compute feature importance using vi_firm() on a logistic regression model made in parsnip. For regex, I will use the iris dataset and try to predict whether an observation is setosa or not.

```
iris1 <- iris %>%
  mutate(class  = case_when(Species == 'setosa' ~ 'setosa',
                            TRUE ~ 'other'))
iris1$class = as.factor(iris1$class)

#set up logistic regression model
iris.lr = logistic_reg(
  mode="classification",
  penalty=NULL,
  mixture=NULL
) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet")

iris.fit = iris.lr %>%
  fit(class ~. , data = iris1)

library(vip)
vip::vi_firm(iris.fit, feature_names = features, train = iris1, type = 'classification')
```

This gives

> Error: Did you mean to use `new_data` instead of `newdata`?

I am also trying to produce partial dependence plots using partial from the related pdp package. I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "glmnet" objects, the correct argument should be `s`, rather than `lambda`, for consistency with `coef.glmnet` (however, calling this with `vi()` currently produces an error due to partial matching with the `scale` argument---I'll push a fix this weekend; https://github.com/koalaverse/vip/issues/103). Also, as of version 0.2.2, vi_model should work directly with model_fit objects. So the correct call here should be:

```
> vi_model(iris_fit, s = iris_fit$fit$lambda[10]). #
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Variable     Importance Sign 
  <chr>             <dbl> <chr>
1 Sepal.Length      0     NEG  
2 Sepal.Width       0     NEG  
3 Petal.Length     -0.721 NEG  
4 Petal.Width       0     NEG
```

As far as `vi_firm()` and `pdp::partial()` are concerned, the easiest thing to do is to create your own prediction wrapper. There should be plenty of details in the docs for each function, and this more examples in our upcoming paper (https://github.com/koalaverse/vip/blob/master/rjournal/RJwrapper.pdf), but here's a basic example:

```
> # Data matrix (features only)
> X <- data.matrix(subset(iris1, select = -class))
> 
> # Prediction wrapper for partial dependence
> pfun <- function(object, newdata) {
+   # Return averaged prediciton for class of interest
+   mean(predict(object, newx = newdata, s = iris_fit$fit$lambda[10], 
+        type = "link")[, 1L])
+ }
> 
> # PDP-based VI
> features <- setdiff(names(iris1), "class")
> vip::vi_firm(
+   object = iris_fit$fit, 
+   feature_names = features, 
+   train = X, 
+   pred.fun = pfun
+ )
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Variable     Importance
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 Sepal.Length       0   
2 Sepal.Width        0   
3 Petal.Length       1.27
4 Petal.Width        0   
> 
> # PDP
> pd <- pdp::partial(iris_fit$fit, "Petal.Length", pred.fun = pfun, 
+                    train = X)
> head(pd)
  Petal.Length      yhat
1     1.000000 1.0644756
2     1.140476 0.9632228
3     1.280952 0.8619700
4     1.421429 0.7607172
5     1.561905 0.6594644
6     1.702381 0.5582116
```

Answer (score 2):

For a regularized model like those fit with glmnet, you might want to stick with the model-specific importance score (the default with `vi()`). Also, notice two things:

- you need to specify which value of `lambda` you want to calculate variable importance at (I just chose one at random here for this example)
- the fitted glmnet object is in `iris_fit$fit`, inside of the parsnip object

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.0 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.5.6      ✓ recipes   0.1.12
#> ✓ dials     0.0.6      ✓ rsample   0.0.6 
#> ✓ dplyr     0.8.5      ✓ tibble    3.0.1 
#> ✓ ggplot2   3.3.0      ✓ tune      0.1.0 
#> ✓ infer     0.5.1      ✓ workflows 0.1.1 
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.1      ✓ yardstick 0.0.6 
#> ✓ purrr     0.3.4
#> ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x purrr::discard()  masks scales::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()   masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()      masks stats::lag()
#> x ggplot2::margin() masks dials::margin()
#> x recipes::step()   masks stats::step()

iris1 <- iris %>%
  mutate(class  = case_when(Species == 'setosa' ~ 'setosa',
                            TRUE ~ 'other'),
         class = factor(class)) %>%
  select(-Species)


iris_mod <- logistic_reg(
  penalty = NULL,
  mixture = NULL
) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet")

iris_fit <- iris_mod %>%
  fit(class ~ ., data = iris1)

library(vip)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'vip'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     vi

vi(iris_fit$fit,
   lambda = iris_fit$fit$lambda[10])
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Variable     Importance Sign 
#>   <chr>             <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 Sepal.Width        3.35 POS  
#> 2 Sepal.Length       0    NEG  
#> 3 Petal.Width       -2.97 NEG  
#> 4 Petal.Length      -3.98 NEG
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The output of `vi()` seems not related to lambda. It generate the same output regardless of lambda values. Does that mean these vi are not model specific? From @bgreenwell, if we use `vi_model(fit, s = iris_fit$fit$lambda[10])` with chosen lambda, the Importance values match output from glmnet output `coef(fit,s = iris_fit$fit$lambda[10]) `. I am kind of lost here, appreciate the help to clarify.