# Integration of Variable importance plots within the tidy modelling framework

Tags: r, tidymodels, tidyverts

Could somebody show me how to generate permutation-based variable implots within the tidy modelling framework? Currently, I have this:

```
library(tidymodels)

# variable importance
final_fit_train %>%
  pull_workflow_fit() %>%
  vip(geom = "point",
      aesthetics = list(color = cbPalette[4],
                        fill = cbPalette[4])) +
  THEME +
  ggtitle("Elastic Net")
```

which generates this:

[image]

However, I would like to have something like this

[image]

It's not clear to me how the rather new tidy modelling framework integrates with the current VIP package. Anybody that could help. Thanks!

https://koalaverse.github.io/vip/articles/vip.html (API of the VIP package).

Answer (score 3):

To compute variable importance using permutation, you need just a few more pieces to put together, compared to using model-dependent variable importance.

Let's look at an example for an SVM model, which does not have model-dependent variable importance score.

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ──────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.1 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.7.0      ✓ recipes   0.1.13
#> ✓ dials     0.0.8      ✓ rsample   0.0.7 
#> ✓ dplyr     1.0.0      ✓ tibble    3.0.3 
#> ✓ ggplot2   3.3.2      ✓ tidyr     1.1.0 
#> ✓ infer     0.5.3      ✓ tune      0.1.1 
#> ✓ modeldata 0.0.2      ✓ workflows 0.1.2 
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.2      ✓ yardstick 0.0.7 
#> ✓ purrr     0.3.4
#> ── Conflicts ─────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x purrr::discard() masks scales::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()  masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()     masks stats::lag()
#> x recipes::step()  masks stats::step()

data("hpc_data")

svm_spec <- svm_poly(degree = 1, cost = 1/4) %>%
  set_engine("kernlab") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

svm_fit <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(svm_spec) %>%
  add_formula(compounds ~ .) %>%
  fit(hpc_data)

svm_fit
#> ══ Workflow [trained] ════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Formula
#> Model: svm_poly()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> compounds ~ .
#> 
#> ── Model ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Support Vector Machine object of class "ksvm" 
#> 
#> SV type: eps-svr  (regression) 
#>  parameter : epsilon = 0.1  cost C = 0.25 
#> 
#> Polynomial kernel function. 
#>  Hyperparameters : degree =  1  scale =  1  offset =  1 
#> 
#> Number of Support Vectors : 2827 
#> 
#> Objective Function Value : -284.7255 
#> Training error : 0.835421
```

Our model is now **trained**, so it's ready for computing variable importance. Notice a couple of steps:

- You `pull()` the fitted model object out of the workflow.
- You have to specify the target/outcome variable, `compounds`.
- In this case, we need to pass both the original training data (use *training* data here, not testing data) and the right underlying function for predicting (this might be tricky to figure out in some cases but for most packages will just be `predict()`).

```r
library(vip)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'vip'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     vi
svm_fit %>%
  pull_workflow_fit() %>%
  vip(method = "permute", 
      target = "compounds", metric = "rsquared",
      pred_wrapper = kernlab::predict, train = hpc_data)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can increase `nsim` here to do this more than once.

Comment: Hi this might work for kernlab (svm), but does not seem to work for a glmnet object. I get the following error: _Error in predict.glmnet(object, newdata = train_x) : You need to supply a value for 'newx'_

Comment: @Pieter-JanInghelbrecht For glmnet I would recommend using model-specific variable importance [as demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606337/computing-importance-measure-using-vip-package-on-a-parsnip-model/61811440#61811440).

Comment: @JuliaSilge can you refer me to a source, or please explain what the "importance" number actually means? Are these the coefficient estimate values per variable?

Comment: @Shai That depends on the specifics of the model. Check out [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332960/what-is-variable-importance) for perspective on what variable importance is, and the [vignette for the **vip** package](https://koalaverse.github.io/vip/articles/vip.html) for some examples

Comment: @JuliaSilge The solution does not work with `tidymodels_1.1.1`, `vip_0.4.1`. Can you please update your answer?