# How to compute FIRM importance measure using VIP package and tidymodels (including recipe)

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidymodels, vip

I want to compute the FIRM importance scores for a model made from a tidymodels workflow.  For regex, I will use the iris dataset and try to predict whether an observation is setosa or not.

```
library(tidymodels)
library(readr)
library(vip)

#clean data
iris <- iris %>%
  mutate(class  = case_when(Species == 'setosa' ~ 'setosa',
                            TRUE ~ 'other'))
iris$class = as.factor(iris$class)
iris <- subset(iris, select = -c(Species))

#split data into training and testing
iris_split = initial_split(iris, prop = 0.8)
cv_splits = vfold_cv(training(iris_split), v = 5)

#preprocessing
iris_recipe = recipe(class ~., data = iris) %>%
  step_center(Sepal.Length) %>%
  prep()

#specify MARS model
model = rand_forest(
  mode = "classification",
  mtry = tune(),
  trees = 50
) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity")

#tuning parameters
tuning_grid = grid_regular(mtry(range=c(1,4)), levels = 4)

iris_wkfl = workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(iris_recipe) %>%
  add_model(model) 
  
iris_tune = tune_grid(iris_wkfl,
            resamples = cv_splits,
            grid = tuning_grid,
            metrics = metric_set(accuracy))

best_params = iris_tune %>%
  select_best(metric = "accuracy")

best_model = finalize_workflow(iris_wkfl, best_params) %>%
  parsnip::fit(data = training(iris_split)) %>%
  pull_workflow_fit()

vip(best_model, method = "firm")
```

The last line produces an error from the pdp package.

Error in get_training_data.default(object) :
The training data could not be extracted from object. Please supply the raw training data using the `train` argument in the call to `partial`.

Is the following line correct? Or do I need to supply for transformed training data using my recipe first? I want to make sure that vip is applying my recipe when computing the importance scores. I know the error says "raw training data" but I am unsure if pdp knows about my workflow.

```
vip(best_model, method = "firm", train = training(iris_split))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to take the same approach that I [outlined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772397/integration-of-variable-importance-plots-within-the-tidy-modelling-framework/62962550#62962550).

Start by tuning and then training your model on the training data:

```r
library(tidymodels)

#clean data
iris = iris %>%
  mutate(class  = case_when(Species == 'setosa' ~ 'setosa',
                            TRUE ~ 'other'),
         class = factor(class)) %>%
  select(-Species)

#split data into training and testing
iris_split = initial_split(iris, prop = 0.8)
iris_train = training(iris_split)
iris_test = testing(iris_split)
cv_splits = vfold_cv(iris_train, v = 5)

#preprocessing
iris_recipe = recipe(class ~., data = iris_train) %>%
  step_center(Sepal.Length)

#specify ranger model
rf_spec = rand_forest(
  mode = "classification",
  mtry = tune(),
  trees = 50
) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity") 
## don't need any importance here if you will do it another way; probably remove

#tuning parameters
tuning_grid = grid_regular(mtry(range=c(1,4)), levels = 4)

iris_wkfl = workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(iris_recipe) %>%
  add_model(rf_spec) 

iris_tune = tune_grid(iris_wkfl,
                      resamples = cv_splits,
                      grid = tuning_grid,
                      metrics = metric_set(accuracy))
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rlang'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     %@%, as_function, flatten, flatten_chr, flatten_dbl, flatten_int,
#>     flatten_lgl, flatten_raw, invoke, list_along, modify, prepend,
#>     splice
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'vctrs'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tibble':
#> 
#>     data_frame
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     data_frame

best_params = iris_tune %>%
  select_best(metric = "accuracy")

rf_fit = finalize_workflow(iris_wkfl, best_params) %>%
  fit(data = iris_train)
```

Your model is now **trained** and you can compute model-independent variable importance scores like FIRM. There are a couple of steps:

- You `pull()` the fitted model out of the workflow.
- You must specify the target/outcome variable, `class`.
- In this case, we need to pass both the original training data (you must use preprocessed *training* data here, which you get out of the recipe) and the right underlying function for predicting from ranger (for most models this is `predict()` but unfortunately for ranger it is `predictions()`).

```r
library(vip)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'vip'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     vi
rf_fit %>%
  pull_workflow_fit() %>%
  vip(method = "firm", 
      target = "class", metric = "accuracy",
      pred_wrapper = ranger::predictions, 
      train = bake(prep(iris_recipe), new_data = NULL))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>